# Stream music through URL on pre installed music player

Tags: android

I am trying to play a music file located on Internet with some URL like "http://......../music.mp3"
I am using the following code

```
Uri myUri = Uri.parse("http://..../music.mp3");
              Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
              intent.setDataAndType(myUri, "audio/*"); 
              startActivity(intent);
```

this code is not playing music in any installed music player, I think it passes the URL so music player is unable to play it. 
I dont want to play music on my app. can anyone give me a hint how to implement it.

Comment: Most Android music players _can't_ do streaming audio, you might have more luck opening your link to your audio file in a web browser instead. Also, implementing a basic streaming music player in your own app is not so hard, and it will make for a smoother user experience, and reduce piracy (users can't just intercept your request to open the player and just download the mp3.)

Comment: Just like internal player fetches the song from URL and downloads and plays it at the same time. Can't we made it done by any external player.something like downloading the song to a temp storage and passing it to external player.But i don't want to download the whole song first and then play it, as it takes time.i want it to download and play at same time

Comment: I don't think internal player does that, at least not the version I have. Yes, you could partially download the song to temp storage and pass that to the player.